# ImportError: cannot import name 'spline' from 'scipy.interpolate'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando con suavizados y encontré este código fuente:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import spline


x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,8,12])

x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),300)
y_smooth = spline(x,y,x_smooth)

plt.plot(x_smooth,y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

Cuando compilo en la terminal este script, me sale este error:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
ImportError: cannot import name 'spline' from 'scipy.interpolate'
```

He instalado scipy y spline pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error. Por alli lei que Spline lo han eliminado y ya no se usa.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que he podido encontrar `spline` fue eliminado en la versión 1.3.1. Posiblemente tengas una versión superior o igual.

Puedes usar para resolverlo `make_interp_spline`. Por lo que tendrías que cambiar:

**De**:

```
from scipy.interpolate import spline
```

**A**:

```
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
```

Y cambiar la forma de usar spline:
**De**:

```
y_smooth = spline(x,y,x_smooth)
```

**A**:

```
y_smooth = make_interp_spline(x,y)(x_smooth)
```

**El código final**:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([1,2,8,12])

x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(),x.max(),300)
y_smooth = make_interp_spline(x,y)(x_smooth)

plt.plot(x_smooth,y_smooth)
plt.show()
```

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes más información en los siguientes enlaces:

- [Interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate)
- [make_interp_spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió de mucho

Comment: ¡Genial! Para eso estamos. Saludos.