# ¿Como puedo sacar los promedios con rolling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hola tengo el siguiente código, por el cual puedo leer y plotear un archivo txt, el cual es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

col_1, col2 = np.loadtxt('experimento_stackoverflow.txt',unpack=True, skiprows=2,usecols=[0,1])

plt.plot(col_1, col2, 'o-')

plt.show()
```

La data del archivo es la siguiente:

```
   Dia        Potencia
    1           10.55
    2           9.45
    3           8.40
    4           3.50
    5           7.36
    6           8.40
    7           9.25
    8           7.20
    9           11.89
    10          12.88
    11          13.99
    12          12.77
    13          11.35
    14          10.10
    15          16.55
    16          14.20
    17          15.23 
    18          13.20
    19          15.14
    20          12.09
```

El plot es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer un suavizado de dos dias en el plot, o mejor dicho quiero sacar los promedios de la columna "Potencia" cada dos dias en sus valores con rolling, para mostrar una nueva curva en el plot.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, Rocker. ¿Qué es lo que intentas? ¿Mostrar la línea de la gráfica como en: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388280/importerror-cannot-import-name-spline-from-scipy-interpolate/388289]?

Comment: No lo que deseo analizar los datos, algo como https://machinelearningmastery.com/moving-average-smoothing-for-time-series-forecasting-python/

Comment: Quiero hacer un suavizado de dos días

Comment: Ya agarras cada dos días con el skiprows... Quieres hacer una regresión local con eso? Puedes usar Savitzky-Golay si es así

Comment: No lo que quiero hacer es sacar los promedios de dos elementos en la columna "Potencia"  y se cree una nueva columna en el txt para poder plotear una nueva curva

Comment: @Adrian tu respuesta estaba buena, no la hubieras borrado

Comment: @Rocker esa nueva traza la quieres colocar junto a la traza anterior? O en una nueva? Edité la pregunta porque creo que me acerco a lo que necesitas, aún no lo tengo muy claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con pandas es fácil. Primero pasé tu data a formato de csv porque no puedo hacerla funcionar como está, jaja... Pero sería algo así:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
df["Potencia"] = df["Potencia"].rolling(2).mean()
df = df.iloc[1::2, :]

print(df)
```

Esto imprime:

```
    Dia  Potencia
1     2    10.000
3     4     5.950
5     6     7.880
7     8     8.225
9    10    12.385
11   12    13.380
13   14    10.725
15   16    15.375
17   18    14.215
19   20    13.615
```

Ya si lo quieres plotear solo haces

```
df.plot(x ='Dia', y='Potencia', kind = 'line', style="o-")
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que intentas suavizar la línea entre los puntos. Podrías utilizar `make_interp_spline` como en tu anterior pregunta:  [make_interp_spline](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388280/importerror-cannot-import-name-spline-from-scipy-interpolate/388289)

- Con `np.loadtxt`: Cargas del txt los datos que necesitas. Esto te
  genera en `col_1` y `col2` un objeto `numpy.ndarray`.
- Con `np.linspace`: devuelves los números espaciados. Más info: [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)
- Con `make_interp_spline`: calculas la interpolación. Más info:  [Interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#module-scipy.interpolate)

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

**Código**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline

col_1, col2 = np.loadtxt('experimento_stackoverflow.txt',unpack=True, skiprows=1,usecols=[0,1])

col_1_smooth = np.linspace(col_1.min(), col_1.max(), 300)
col2_smooth = make_interp_spline(col_1, col2)(col_1_smooth)

plt.plot(col_1_smooth, col2_smooth)
plt.show()
```

**Resultado**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A diferencia de la respuesta de tu otra pregunta, he hecho un cambio a mayores, he cambiado el mínimo y el máximo que necesitas cogiendo solamente la columna 1 como rango ya que indicas que necesitas hacerlo en un rango de días:

```
col_1_smooth = np.linspace(col_1.min(), col_1.max(), 300)
```

Si necesitas los dos primeros días, puedes pasar como parámetro directamente 1 y 2:

```
col_1_smooth = np.linspace(1, 2, 300)
```

También podrías usar:

```
col_1_smooth = np.linspace(col_1[0], col_1[1], 300)
```

Ya que son los dos primeros elementos.

De esta forma, el resultado sería el siguiente:

**Resultado**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**: cuando cargas el txt con `np.loadtxt`, estás usando `skiprows=2`, esto no solo obvia la fila que indica "Día | Potencia", te está eliminando la segunda fila que es la que comienza en el día 1, por lo qué te he cambiado a `skiprows=1`.

**Código final**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline

col_1, col2 = np.loadtxt('experimento_stackoverflow.txt',unpack=True, skiprows=1,usecols=[0,1])

col_1_smooth = np.linspace(col_1[0], col_1[1], 300)
col2_smooth = make_interp_spline(col_1, col2)(col_1_smooth)

plt.plot(col_1_smooth, col2_smooth)
plt.show()
```

**EDITO**:

La forma de sacar una nueva columna donde hagas una media de cada dos días podría ser la siguiente:

1. Recorro los elementos de la columna de 'Potencia'.
2. Cada dos elementos los sumo y los divido entre dos (de ahí saco la
   media).
3. Los voy añadiendo a una lista (de allí los corchetes []).
4. Luego los convierto en un array de numpy con `np.array`

```
col3 = np.array([(col2[i]+col2[i+1])/2 for i in range(0, len(col2), 2)])
```

Si imprimo el contenido de `col3`, me arroja lo siguiente:

```
[10.     5.95   7.88   8.225 12.385 13.38  10.725 15.375 14.215 13.615]
```

Donde cada elemento es la media solicitada.

En `col_1_smooth` cambié la dimensión. Ya que ahora los elementos de la media son 10, por lo qué, si dejamos otra dimensión, habrá un error. Con un 10 coloco la misma dimensión tanto para x como para y.

**El código (de ejemplo) sería el siguiente**:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, BSpline

col_1, col2 = np.loadtxt('experimento_stackoverflow.txt',unpack=True, skiprows=1,usecols=[0,1])
col3 = np.array([(col2[i]+col2[i+1])/2 for i in range(0, len(col2), 2)])

col_1_smooth = np.linspace(col_1.min(), col_1.max(), 10)

plt.plot(col_1_smooth, col3)
plt.show()
```

**Resultado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Digo de ejemplo porque aún no se entiende muy bien como quieres la traza. Pero creo que nos acercamos a lo que necesitas. Si es posible, edita la pregunta con más detalles o ejemplos para tratar de acertar con lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias Adrian, pero lo que necesito es un suavizado que se de cada dos días, en todo el plot, es posible?

Answer (score 1):

Según el [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/moving-average-smoothing-for-time-series-forecasting-python/) que compartes en tu comentario, basta con cambiar el parámetro `window` de 3 a 2

```
from pandas import read_table
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

#Leemos los datos con read_table en lugar de np.loadtxt
data = read_table('experimento_stackoverflow.txt',
                  header = 0,index_col=0,delimiter= "\s+")
print(data.head())

#Aquí es donde cambiamos el parámetro 
rolling = data.rolling(window=2)
rolling_mean = rolling.mean()

data.plot()
rolling_mean.plot(color = 'red')
pyplot.show()
```